# How to completely stop/kill spark Structured Streaming jobs in AWS EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

I'm running Spark Structured Streaming Jobs in AWS EMR, but when I canceled a job, even putting to cancel and force the stop the streaming job doesn't stop.
And If I Submit again the same job I have two equal jobs working at the same time.
At the follow image we will see the first 3 equal jobs running at the same time, even after I canceled the first and the second jobs.
[image: AWS EMR Spark UI with Spark Structured Streaming jobs who doesn't stop]

So,I want some help if someone know how can I stop completely a spark structured streaming job at AWS EMR without drop the cluster ?
Thank You !